# create custom tableviewcell within a view

Tags: iphone, xcode, view, uitableview

I'm trying to create a custom tableviewcell within a view.  Specifically, I want to display an image and labels above my table.  I'm also using the tab bar at the bottom.  All the sample code I'm finding uses a 3 nib approach: 1 rootviewcontroller, 1 mainwindow, and 1 with the custom table cell in it.  I don't see how to load the custom view nib into a window that has other stuff in it.  Sorry for the long question everyone!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://www.bdunagan.com/2009/06/28/custom-uitableviewcell-from-a-xib-in-interface-builder/) explains how to load a custom table cell from a NIB file.  It's pretty easy once you see how it's done.

Comment: Yes, i have a basic app working now.  On some of the more complex interfaces that I'm trying to create I am still having trouble adding more than one section of tableview at a time.  Meaning when I want to list details x,y,and z on the top half of the screen and display 3 unrelated lists from other tables on the bottom half of the screen.  I ordered a couple more advanced books. I'll post what I find out.  Thanks again!